# NDK - Create 16 bit rgb struct in C++

Tags: android, c++, image-processing, android-ndk, java-native-interface

I wanna create a struct in C++ like this, which is for ARGB_8888 format:

```
typedef struct
{
    uint8_t alpha;
    uint8_t red;
    uint8_t green;
    uint8_t blue;
} argb;
```

But for the RGB_565 format, i.e. R and B: 5 bits each, G : 6 bits.

Comment: Is there a particular reason that you cannot leave them as 8 bit integers and simply ignore the top bits that are unneeded?

Answer (score 0):

Try using bitfields. The syntax would be as follows:

```
typedef struct
{
    uint8_t alpha;
    uint8_t red:5;
    uint8_t green:6;
    uint8_t blue:5;
} argb;
```

This may not work exactly as you'd expect depending on what machine this code is targeted for.

See the section "6. Bitfields" at this link:
[structure-packing](http://www.catb.org/esr/structure-packing/)

Comment: Thanks, My code will be running on android devices. will this work as expected on them?

Comment: Not sure. I'm not super familiar with Android devices, nor exactly how this structure packing method works. If I had to guess, I think this will work because 5+6+5=16 bits which is exactly 2 bytes. If it didn't come out to be an exact number of bytes, then space would be wasted.

Comment: Try printing sizeof(argb) and see what number it gives. The number it returns will be the size in bytes of the struct type argb. If the structure packing method worked, this would come out to be 3 bytes.